# Sending multiple DIV container content in a single form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

This form submit was actually working completely fine until I tried to reformat it for a more user friendly version. The form is extremely long and has 32 fields in it, so I thought I could visually break them down into collapsable div containers so that the user can expand only the section they wanted to update. It's essentially a profile page for a DND website, so the fields call the data that is in the SQL database and displays it, and the user can update them and submit any changes they want to make. The fields are displaying the correct data still, but after completing these changes nothing happens when the submission button is clicked.

Is it possible to use this method to transmit data to the MySQL database, or is there a better way to create a collapsable section to keep the form working as it's already set up?

The only things that were changed about the code was the addition of:

```
<input class="toggle-box1" id="identifier-1" type="checkbox" >
<label for="identifier-1"> ORIGINAL SECTION TITLE</label>
<div>FORUM FIELDS</div
```

Here is a selection of the original code, it is not all of the code:

```
<h3>Character Detials</h3>
<h6>Character Name:</h6>
<input name="Charname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Charname']; ?>" size="40" /> 
<br>
<p></p>
<h6>Trillian ID:</h6>
<input name="YahooID" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['YahooID']; ?>" size="40" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6>Title:</h6>
<input name="Title" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Title']; ?>" size="40" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6>Race:</h6>
<input name="Race" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Race']; ?>" size="40" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6>Birth Place:</h6>
<input name="BirthPlace" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['BirthPlace']; ?>" size="40"/><br>
<p></p>
<h6>Apparent Age:</h6>
<input name="ApparentAge" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ApparentAge']; ?>" size="40"/><br>
<p></p>
<h6>Actual Age:</h6>
<input name="ActualAge" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ActualAge']; ?>" size="40" /> 
<br>
<p></p>
<h6>Height:</h6>
<input name="Height" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Height']; ?>" size="40" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6>Weight:</h6>
<input name="Weight" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Weight']; ?>" size="40" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6>Hair Color:</h6>
<input name="HairColor" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['HairColor']; ?>" size="40" /> 
<br>
<p></p>
<h6>Eye Color:</h6>
<input name="EyeColor" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['EyeColor']; ?>" size="40" /> 
<br>
<p></p>
```

And after the change:

```
    <input class="toggle-box1" id="identifier-1" type="checkbox" >
<label for="identifier-1"><h6 style="font-size:32px">Character Details</h6></label>
<div><h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:0px 0px 10px;">Character Name:</h6>
<input name="Charname" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Charname']; ?>" size="28" />
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Trillian ID:</h6>
<input name="YahooID" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['YahooID']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Title:</h6>
<input name="Title" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Title']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Race:</h6>
<input name="Race" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Race']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Birth Place:</h6>
<input name="BirthPlace" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['BirthPlace']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Apparent Age:</h6>
<input name="ApparentAge" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ApparentAge']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Actual Age:</h6>
<input name="ActualAge" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ActualAge']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Height:</h6>
<input name="Height" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Height']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Weight:</h6>
<input name="Weight" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Weight']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Hair Color:</h6>
<input name="HairColor" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['HairColor']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p>
<h6 style="font-size:32px; padding:18px 0px 10px;">Eye Color:</h6>
<input name="EyeColor" style="font-size:30px;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['EyeColor']; ?>" size="28" /><br>
<p></p></div>
```

Comment: *nothing happens when the submission button is clicked*, could you create a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run your code help you out. Or an alternative where we can check out your form.

Comment: where is your form submission? Do you actually use the form element, or just inputs?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I apologize, I am not understanding how to make a stack snippet from that page link, but here is the website page link:

https://m.houseofblackflame.com/submitchara.php
It will require you to log in - user: testing pass: Testpassword

The original form will be updated as well, if I can get the same expandable fields working, the non mobile version of this form that is working, is at https://www.houseofblackflame.com/submitchara.php

Answer (score 2):

To collect and send data of all of your `<input>` elements to the server you should add a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) element wrapping all of your inputs.

```
<form action="/yourbackendendpoint.php" method="POST">
  <label for="field-first-name">Your first name</label>
  <input type="text" id="field-first-name" name="first-name" />
  <button type="submit">Submit the form</button>
</form>
```

The form element needs a bit of info from you, like where the data should be sent. Usually you send it to a backend endpoint or file where you validate and process the input of the user. You can specify this endpoint or file in the `action` attribute.

The `method` attribute determines the HTTP method used for sending or retrieving the data. Since you want to update the data I'd recommend that you use the `POST` method. Be sure that your server expects the same method as the frontend sends.

Check if every one of your `<input>` elements has a valid `name` attribute value. This value will be the key that you will select your values with on the backend, like so:

```
<!-- name = first-name, value = Mike -->
<input type="text" id="field-first-name" name="first-name" value="Mike" />
```

The `first-name` key has now a value of `Mike`. When you send that you can get it with:

```
$_POST[ 'first-name' ] // 'Mike'
```

I hope this clears some thing up for you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask here below.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All of this is already built into the form. The only elements that were changed were the additions of the labels. I have updated the OP with additional code. I did provide you with some test login details to see how the desktop form ( which is working normally, ) and the new Mobile form works.

Comment: Have you considered that there is some client side validation blocking the submit with JavaScript?

Comment: All of this already existed, however because of your post I noticed my form post method at the top was accidentally removed somewhere along the lines of my editing. Returning those original lines of code works perfect now. However, I have a field there that I no longer need, and removing that field breaks the form submission again. I am going to have to dive deeper into it. I no longer need the spryfield1.

Answer (score 1):

While discussing this issue with Emiel, I noticed somewhere along the lines of my editing for the form for the new mobile version I had accidentally deleted the form post method that is required at the top / beginning of the forum, doh

Thank you for your help everyone!

Answer (score -1):

I noticed you use a `<h6> </h6>` tag inside a `<label> </label>`. Per HTML specifications this is not allowed and supposed to be done like this. Maybe your problem is resulting from that issue.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, the form is already set up this way and working normally with the h tags, and this is not the cause of the issue. It is the addition of the code I outlined that is breaking the form submission.

Comment: Update: removing every single H tag and changing it to <p style> did not change the issue in any way. When clicking the submission button nothing is happening. It doesn't even redirect to the success or failure page. Just nothing happens.